# Visual list of Flex components

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Is there web page (Adobe or other) that visually shows all the available Flex UI components? (similar to Java Swing's [A Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a web version of Tour De Flex on http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/, it doesn't include the AIR only components, to get those you will need to install the AIR version from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html

Comment: I agree, Tour De Flex. Its the most comprehensive list I've found, and some of the examples (with code) should inspire.